# Getting the same angle marks using pgfplots as those using TikZ

Tags: pgfplots

I am using pgfplots to draw intersecting lines.  Three right triangles are made by these intersecting lines - two of them in the third.  I am trying to mark the two pairs of acute angles of equal measures in the smaller right triangles by marks made by `TikZ` with the commands `\tkzMarkAngle[size=0.5cm,mark=|](B,A,P);` and `\tkzMarkAngle[size=0.5cm,mark=||](A,B,P);`, and I am trying to mark any right angles by the same mark made by `TikZ` with the command `\tkzMarkRightAngle(A,P,B);`.  How do I mark the acute angles of equal measure in the following code?  Unlike with `TikZ`, I know that have to make the right-angle marks manually.  What is the length of each side of the right angle mark that is made by `TikZ`? (I have diagrams of right triangles - not drawn on the coordinate axes - drawn using `TikZ` on other pages; I want the right-angle marks that I have to manually make to be identical to the right angle marks drawn by `TikZ`.)

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings}
\usepackage{mathtools,systeme,array}

\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}



\begin{document}

\noindent \hspace*{\fill}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=6in,axis equal image,clip=false,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-5,xmax=10,samples=501,
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    ymin=-8,ymax=11,
    restrict y to domain=-8:11,
    enlargelimits={abs=0.25cm},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white},
    xtick={\empty},ytick={\empty},
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
]
\addplot[samples=501, latex-latex,domain=-5:10,blue] {x + 1} node[anchor=north west,pos=0.9,font=\footnotesize]{$y = mx + b$};
\addplot[samples=501, latex-latex,domain=-5:10,blue] {3 - x} node[anchor=south west,pos=0.9,font=\footnotesize]{$y = m^{\prime}x + b^{\prime}$};
\addplot [dashed, latex-latex,domain=-21:21] (6,x) node [pos=0.1, anchor=north, font=\footnotesize, sloped]{$x=x_{\circ}$};
\addplot [dashed, domain=1:6] {2};
(1,2) coordinate (B);
\draw [fill] (1,2) circle [radius=1.5pt] node[label=above:$B$]{};
(6,-3) coordinate (A);
\draw [fill] (6,-3) circle [radius=1.5pt] node[label=right:$A$]{};
(6,7) coordinate (C);
\draw [fill] (6,7) circle [radius=1.5pt] node[label=right:$C$]{};
(6,2) coordinate (P);
\draw [fill] (6,2) circle [radius=1.5pt] node[label=right:$P$]{};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace{\fill}
\vskip0.25in

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`tzplot`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tzplot):

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{tzplot}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.6,font=\scriptsize]
%\tzhelplines(-5,-8)(10,10)
\tzaxes(-5,-8)(11,11){$x$}[br]{$y$}[ar]
\def\Fx{1+\x}
\def\Gx{3-\x}
\tzfn[blue,<->]\Fx[-5:10]{$y=mx+b$}[b=1cm]
\tzfn[blue,<->]\Gx[-5:10]{$y=m'x+b'$}[a=1cm]
\tzXpoint*{Fx}{Gx}(B){$B$}
\tzvfnat[dashed,<->]"vline"{6}[-8:10]{$x=x^\circ$}[sloped,b,pos=.1]
\tzXpoint*{Fx}{vline}(C){$C$}[0]
\tzXpoint*{Gx}{vline}(A){$A$}[0]
\tzcoor*($(A)!(B)!(C)$)(P){$P$}[0]
\tzline[dashed](B)(P)
% angle marks
\tzrightanglemark[thin](C)(B)(A)(30pt)
\tzanglemark*[red](C)(B)(P)
\tzanglemark'[double](A)(B)(P)(20pt)
\tzrightanglemark(B)(P)(C)(15pt)
\tzrightanglemark*[blue](A)(P)(B)(15pt)
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```